# ReactJS: How to show links in column in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I have below code. I fetch the data from back end and show as a table. This works fine. Now my task is to show 1st column in table as a link. How can I do that?

```
const EditController = () => {

    const initState = [
        {name: "", ipaddr: "", port: 0, sshuser: "", sshport: 0, license: ""},
    ];
    
    const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    
    const fetchControllers = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/exec/editcontroller', {user} , {headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': token,
            }}).then( function (res) {
                
                if(res.status === 200) {
                    setState(res.data);
                }else {
                    return 'failure';
                }
                
            });
        }catch(err) {
            return 'error';
        }
    }
    
    useEffect ( () => {
       console.log('Inside useEffect');
       fetchControllers();
    }, []);
        
    return (
        <div className="medium-text">
            <div className="center">
                <h2>Controllers</h2>
                <table id="tbl">
                
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>IP Address</th>
                            <th>Port</th>
                            <th>SSH User</th>
                            <th>SSH Port</th>
                            <th>License</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                
                    
                    {state.map((item) => (
                        <tr key={item.id}>
                        {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
                            <td>{val}</td>
                        ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                
                </table>    
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default {EditController};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way - use index in map function.

```
 {Object.values(item).map((val, index) =>
    index === 0 ? (
        <td>
            <Link href='/'>{val}</Link>
        </td>
            ) : (
        <td>{val}</td>
            )
        )}
```